# "Interested" is to "interesting" as "curious" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

I can't find any perfect matches in dictionaries. Does there exist such a word at all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Interested* is your feeling and *interesting* is the property of the thing that interests you. *Curious* refers to both the feeling of the person and the property of the thing, so your answer is: *curious*.

Comment: "They call him Aslan in That Place," said Eustace. "What a curious name!"  "Not half so curious as himself."

Comment: My problem is I don't understand why the word curious is being used much more often in the former sense than in the latter. Instead, many other words such as "interesting" or "intriguing" are being used for I don't know what reasons.

Comment: @Terry LiYifeng: One obvious reason is that *"I am curious"* is potentially ambiguous. The more so when you consider that you'd invariably use that to mean you're *interested*, but you'd almost always intend the other meaning with *"You are curious"*. In such circumstances, people look for alternative words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good explanation. Thanks for clearing my confusion.